# Space between DIV and Top

Tags: html, css

I have a space between the top of my website and the top div, I have set both to have no margins but it still has a space. Can anyone tell me what it is I am doing wrong here? I thought setting the margins to 0 would fix it but apparently not.

HTML

```
<div class="topPanel">
<p>TITLE</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topPanel
{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
width:100%;
height:auto;
font-family: Copperplate, "Copperplate Gothic Light", fantasy;
color:#000000;
font-weight:100;
font-size:36px;
text-align:center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}

body
{
background-color:#E3E3E3;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}
```

Sample image
[image: Sample image]

Comment: Try setting the margins to 0 on the paragraph tag.

Comment: It's actually a very normal mistake, it's a known CSS *feature* (called `collapsing margins`). However, silly question, a simply google search would suffice since every web designer has found it at some point (;

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the margin on your `p` tag is pushing your div down.

The possible solutions are:

1) Change your `p` style to have zero top margin

or

2) Add `padding-top: 1px` to your div

or

3) Add some `border-top` to your div.

If the `p` tag has margin, but nothing to "push off of" within the div, the entire div will move down to accomodate the margin-top of the `p` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers set default padding/margin values for certain tags, specially `body`, `head` and `html`, which contain all elements inside them. So you may set them to a value of `0px` to be sure you get what you want.

```
html, head, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, make sure the `p` tag itself doesn't have any kind of padding/margin, as well as your `div` (`div`s don't have any by default, but just to be sure):

```
p, div {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Never seen anyone try to style the head element before... Also this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The problem may be either the `p` tag's margins or the containing element's (`body` and even `html`) padding values, as I said, some browsers set default values for them.